# Sending a DatagramPacket from one PC to another over a LAN

Tags: java, networking, udp

I want Peer(s) to be able to send DatagramPackets over a WIFI LAN for the sole purpose of discovering other Peers.  So, I have each Peer made up of a Client(Sending packets) and a Server (listening for packets).

I have only been able to get this to work by using IPConfig on each machine to get their respective IPv4 Address and then using that as a paramter for the creation of the DatagramPacket:-

```
InetAddress server = InetAddress.getByName("THE IPv4 ADDRESS OF THE PEER'S SERVER
                                            RUNNING ON THE OTHER MACHINE");

DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(outBuffer, outBuffer.length,
                                               server, serverPort);
```

Am I using broadcast (for peer discovery) in the right way here because it seems pretty rubbish to me if I am?  I was under the assumption I could have a client on machineA fire off a packet into the LAN abyss and the Server running on machineB would be listening to the entire LAN and detect the packet.  At the moment all I'm doing is manually using IPConfig on the machine running the server and typing that address in the DatagramPacket on the machine running the client, which just seems pointless.

I can use multicast just fine but I think broadcast is more what I need for peer discovery.

Help appreciated.

Comment: See http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc792 for ICMP discovery without installing anything on hosts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the broadcast address `255.255.255.255` for both server and client.

Comment: See http://nmap.org/book/man.html, this man indicates "ping broadcast may be ignored".

Comment: @Aubin it's a UDP packet, not an ICMP ping

Answer (score 1):

That's not really broadcast, since you're giving the server's address, rather than the broadcast address (`255.255.255.255`, or whatever your local network broadcast address is (like `192.168.1.255`, if your network segment is `192.168.1.0/24`).

You also may consider that you could have a firewall blocking incoming UDP packets on your server port. You should look at the documentation for DatagramSocket/DatagramPacket to see if there's a magic incantation for binding the server socket properly, or sending the packet from the client properly.

[**Edit**: How to find the network broadcast]
The network broadcast address can be found once you know the network address, both of which you can tell from your IP and subnet mask. The subnet mask basically shows how much of the address is the network, and how much is the client. (subnet mask is often written as "netmask") An example:

IP: 192.168.1.101
Netmask: 255.255.255.0
Network Address (CIDR): 192.168.1.0/24
Broadcast Address: 192.168.1.255

or:

IP: 10.13.28.55
Netmask: 255.255.0.0
Network: 10.13.0.0/16
Broadcast Address: 10.13.255.255

So essentially, the network address has a bunch of zeroes at the end, and the broadcast address replaces them with ones.

IPv4 Addresses are 32-bit numbers (easiest to think of them as unsigned. If you do the bitwise-AND of your address and the netmask, you get the network address. If you bitwise-OR that with the bitwise-NOT of the netmask, you get the broadcast address (so `(addr & netmask) | ~netmask)` would get you the local broadcast).

`255.255.255.255` (or `0xFFFFFFFF`) is the global broadcast address. IP broadcasts don't cross network segments, so it's safe to send to it, though.

Comment: I just used 255.255.255.255 and it worked :).  Its interesting because that address is not listed when I do an IPConfig.  255.255.255.0 is listed as the Subnet Mask.  Apart from experience how can you find the broadcast address of a LAN?  If I was to take my program and run it on a LAN where the broadcast address is not 255.255.255.255 then the program would not work.  Is it possible to discover at runtime the broadcast address of the LAN the program is executing in?